# Get outer json key value into very json in the nested json array using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON like this

```json
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "something",
  "list": [
    {
      "A": "Something"
    },
    {
      "B": "Something1"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like is to do is add **id** and **name** to both the JSON's present inside **list**
I've gone through a couple of questions and I couldn't find anywhere where somebody had done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following Shift spec will work:

```
{
    "id|name": "&",
    "list": {
      "*": {
        "@(2,id)": "&2.[&1].id",
        "@(2,name)": "&2.[&1].name",
        "*": "&2.[&1].&"
      }
    }
}
```

With your sample data, the output produced was:

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "something",
    "list": [{
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "something",
        "A": "Something"
    }, {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "something",
        "B": "Something1"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Yes I had already figured it out, this is what I did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This spec should give you what you want:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "list": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,id)": "&2.[&1].id",
          "@(2,name)": "&2.[&1].name",
          "*": "&2.[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

With your input it gives the following as output:

```
{
  "list" : [ {
    "A" : "Something",
    "id" : "1234",
    "name" : "something"
  }, {
    "B" : "Something1",
    "id" : "1234",
    "name" : "something"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Oops didn't see James had answered already, sorry about that! Looks like you can choose between the two depending on whether you want the original top-level fields in the outgoing JSON, although you can just remove his id|name entry and get what I had. Upvote his, I should've refreshed the page before submitting :)